# ASP.net DropDownList - Visiblility

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, autopostback

I have the following DropDownList, car_make, when I select BMW I would like the dropdownlist bmw to show up, I have set it to Visible = false by default, I have the code in my CS file in the pageload, however that is making the whole page to refresh, how can I just make the dropdownlist appear without refreshing the whole page? Thank you.

ASP.Net code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="car_make" runat="server" Width="100%" ForeColor="Black">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>BMW</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Benz</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>



<asp:DropDownList ID="bmw" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible = "false" ForeColor="Black">
    <asp:ListItem>Model 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Model 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Model 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Page.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (car_make.Text == "BMW")
        {
            bmw.Visible = true;


        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [Updatepanel](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/documentation/live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx). It won't refresh the whole page.

Here one example with your provided sample

**Source :**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="car_make" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" Width="100%" ForeColor="Black" OnSelectedIndexChanged="car_make_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>BMW</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Benz</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>



                <asp:DropDownList ID="bmw" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="false" ForeColor="Black">
                    <asp:ListItem>Model 1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Model 2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Model 3</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**CODE :**

```
protected void car_make_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (car_make.Text == "BMW")
     bmw.Visible = true; 
   else
     bmw.Visible = false;
}
```

What's new here in **Source** part is [AutoPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx) which needed to get change. Another is [OnSelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: While this is correct, your answer would be more useful with an example.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! Much appreciated, very helpful. may I ask you a question? Should I use UpdatePanel I I want to call a value from the databse when I select BMW and Model 1? Do I just put my Select statement code in the car_make_SelectedIndexChanged? Or there is another method? thank you!

Comment: Well, i always prefer updatepanel in webforms. if your "bmw" dropdown also have task they you have to also add autopostback and OnSelectedIndexChanged event in bmv event. check my updated answer i have added some references that might help you.thanks :)